# Grails/GORM dynamic finder to get the domain by its relation ID instead of relation object itself

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, relational-database, grails-orm

grailsVersion=3.2.9,
gormVersion=6.0.10

Say, we have two grails domains:

```
class A {
   int id
   B b
}

class B {
   int id
}
```

Now, if I have an ID of some `B` in my code(say I have that ID in an enum), to get an instance of `A` by ID of `B` using GORM dynamic finder the only way is the following:

```
A.findByB(B.get(bId))
```

which does cause an additional query to get the `B` instance and that is not ideal.

So is there any way, maybe some Grails/GORM plugin, adding a support for the following:

```
A.findByBId(bId)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `A.findByB(B.load(bId))` to avoid fetching the `B` object.

http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/load.html